# SQL Update table from one database from other table from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to perform an update from a table in one database from another table in another database. One table has a number of lat/lon and I want to update the other one with those based on the matching address.

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE
    WENS_IMPORT.dbo.new_import 
SET
 WENS_IMPORT.dbo.new_import.lat = WENS.dbo.SUBSCRIPTION.lat,
 WENS_IMPORT.dbo.new_import.lon = WENS.dbo.SUBSCRIPTION.lon
FROM
 WENS.dbo.SUBSCRIPTION AS Table_A
 INNER JOIN WENS_IMPORT.dbo.new_import AS Table_B
    ON Table_A.streetAddress = Table_B.Address
WHERE
 Table_A.account_id = '388' AND Table_A.active = '1'
```

I thought this was the best route but I keep getting this error returned:

> ERROR: The multi-part identifier "WENS.dbo.SUBSCRIPTION.lat"
> could not be bound. Error Code: 4104

Is this because it is seeing a number of records that match the address?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: From the documentation, when you use `UPDATE` with `FROM/JOIN` with aliases, you `UPDATE Alias` not `UPDATE tablename`. So you want `UPDATE Table_B`

Comment: @DaleK Oddly enough, you can actually use the original table name in the first line, on condition it was only referenced once. I *strongly* advise against it though as it's confusing. It didn't work here because it was used on the *right-hand* side of the `SET` expressions

Comment: @DaleK So do I, my point was that the issue they were facing wasn't related to the first line, and fixing that would not have helped. What did help is changing the right side

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for the responses. Dale was spot on and I went ahead and changed the alias' and it worked!

Here's the code for any other who has this issue:

```
 UPDATE
     Table_B
 SET
  Table_B.lat = Table_A.lat,
  Table_B.lon = Table_A.lon
 FROM
  WENS.dbo.SUBSCRIPTION AS Table_A
  INNER JOIN WENS_IMPORT.dbo.new_import AS Table_B
     ON Table_A.streetAddress = Table_B.Address
  WHERE
   Table_A.account_id = '388' AND Table_A.active = '1'
```

Comment: Left hand side of `SET` doesn't need the alias as you can only set the columns of one table at a time anyway. [Consider using better aliases rather than a b c](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3), as well as not using three-part table names (just set your database correctly)

Answer (score -1):

You can not use 4 part name unless you use Linked Server .
As you asked your both databases are attached to a same server . In this case use this pattern .<Owner/Schema>.  . For example : WENS_IMPORT.dbo.new_import
in fieldName it is not neseccery to Add table name Use:
Set Table_B.lat=Table_A.lat

good luck

Comment: Thanks for responding... So you mean it should be duo.new_import? Won't the server think the table is in the same database? And yes both db are on the same MSSQL server. Thanks!